# How do I link a function to a div with a tags that represent a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

**I have this code in html representing a navbar**

```
<div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Categories 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a id="gc" href="#">GameComputers</a>
          <a id="ws" href="#">WorkStations</a>
          <a id="lt" href="#">Laptops</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <a href="pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="#news">Cart</a>
    </div>
```

*In javascript I am doing this trying to show an alert when the a tag is clicked*

```
function ShowGameComputers()
{
  let test = document.getElementById("gc");
  if(test == clicked)
  {
    alert("clicked");
  }
}
```

- I call the function like this in my Init function
  `ShowGameComputers();`

Comment: `if (test == clicked)` will error on you if that's your code. Do you know how to add an eventlistener to an element? Do you know how to add inline click events in the HTML?

Comment: yes and yes but to be clean I am not allowed to use html inline events

Answer (score 1):

Using **<a>** instead of button is a bad practice. you can only make it behave like button by using a meaningless **href** attribute that prevents users from navigating to another page.

For screen readers, **<a>** with emtpy href is not a button.

Fore more info, follow these links.

[Anchors vs Buttons](https://bitsofco.de/anchors-vs-buttons/)

[When To Use The Button Element](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/)

---

Attach an onclick event handler directly on element#gc. Use on of thsese two.

```js
const test = document.getElementById("gc");

test.onclick = () => {
  alert("Test Clicked")
}
```

```html
<button id="gc" type="button">Test</button>
```

---

```js
   function testClick() {
      alert("Test Clicked")
    }
```

```html
<button id="gc" type="button" onClick="testClick()">Test</button>
```

Comment: This wont work since it is an a tag and not a button?!

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: @OfficialRules Follow the rules. Don't use <a> instead of button. If you need a button to look like a link, change its style using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use html inline elements, you can achieve it with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#gc").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Categories 
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a id="gc" href="#">GameComputers</a>
          <a id="ws" href="#">WorkStations</a>
          <a id="lt" href="#">Laptops</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <a href="pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="#news">Cart</a>
    </div>
```